# Adjective to describe that a date is now in the past

Tags: word-request, adjective-phrases, dates

I'm trying to formulate to a website user that he can't modify a date anymore because this date is now in the past.

So for I'm at "You can't modify a campaign start date after it's exceeded" (campaign here means advertising campaign, if that's of importance), but I have a gut feel that "exceeded" is incorrect, and that the sentence is overall weak.

Is there a better adjective ? Should I fully reformulate ?

Comment: There are several stack exchange conversations re **past dates** and **dates in the past**, which are probably the phrases you require. See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192313/date-has-already-passed-or-date-has-already-past     and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923988/how-to-check-if-the-date-is-in-the-past-in-php

Comment: Indeed, I reworded to "You can't modify a campaign start date once it is passed" which feels better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to express that idea. Here's one:

> A campaign's start-date cannot be changed after the campaign has started.

P.S. Another way is to use **once**:

> Once a campaign has started, its start-date cannot be changed.